# Template for displaying CPT / Taxonomy URL issues

Tags: posts, customization, urls

I would like to create a template to display custom post's terms.

First menu level page :

(Drink - About / LOGO / Questions - Contact )

---

Section 1 (Drink Page) :

(col-6) -> Image / (col-6) -> Page Presentation Text

Section 2 :

(col-4) -> First Term / (col-4) -> Second Term / (col-4) -> Third Term

---

On click, i would like to display the first post assigned to it's term.

Exemple :

- For the first menu level -> www.mysite.com/drinks/
  On this page, on 2nd section -> First term (Wine), Second Term (Hard), Third Term (Soft)

On click, by example on Hard, i would like somethink like this -> www.mysite.com/drinks/hard/post-name

--

Currently : 
- My first menu item, is a PAGE.

When i click on the first term, my url is -> www.mysite.com/custom-post/post-name and not www.mysite.com/first-menu-page/post-name

I would likd to use the same template for multiple page, with multiple custom post..

I a junior developper and it's a little bit hard to explain..

Below, my current code :

```
<!-- SECTION 1 -->
<section class="main-page ptb-60" id="main-page">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-7 page-content">
                <!-- Image -->
                <?php 

                $image = get_field('page_image');

                if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- Image -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-5">
                <!-- Presentation Text -->
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_field('page_description'); ?></p>
                <hr>
                <p class="intro-texte pb-20"><?php the_field('page_introduction'); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_field('page_content'); ?></p>
                <!-- Presentation Text -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
<!-- SECTION 1 -->

<!-- SECTION 2 -->
<section class="sous-pages ptb-60 bg-g" id="sous-pages">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row ptb-30">
            <div class="col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h3><?php the_field('section_title'); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">  


            <?php

                $taxonomy = get_field('taxonomy');

                $terms = get_terms(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                ));



                if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
                // Run a loop and print them all
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                        "posts_per_page" => 1,
                        "orderby" => 'date', // this is the default
                        "order" => 'DESC', // this is the default
                        "tax_query" => array(
                            array (
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, // use the $tax you define at the top of your script
                            'field' => 'term_id',
                            'terms' => $term->term_id, // use the current term in your foreach loop
                            ),
                        ),
                        ) ); ?>

                        <!--LOOP CONTENT -->
                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-20 cpt-categories">

                                <div class="cat-images">
                                <!-- Image -->
                                <?php 

                                $image = get_field('image_category', $term);

                                if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img-fluid pb-20" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- Image -->
                            </div>


                            <?php $pageone = get_the_permalink($the_query->posts[0]); ?>

                            <h4><a href="<?php echo $pageone; ?>"><?= $term->name ?></a></h4>
                                <?php echo $cat; ?>
                        </div>
                        <!--LOOP CONTENT -->

            <?php
            } // End foreach
            } // End if 
            ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</section>
<!-- SECTION 2 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [The WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), you must create a taxonomy template.

Basically, you have two options:

**1) taxonomy.php:** if all terms share the same design.

**2) taxonomy-{slug}.php:** if each term has its own design (different colors, layout etc).